# создать копию таблицы в yii

Tags: yii

есть таблица с названием first на основе нее нужно создать миграцию в ней (в миграции) создать таблицу first_buplicate, то есть  сделать (CREATE TABLE first_buplicate LIKE first) но через миграции

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->createCommand('CREATE TABLE first_buplicate SELECT * FROM first')->execute();
```